# How can I make the line-height of equations in MediaWiki equal to that of normal text (to make it flow)?

Tags: math, mediawiki, css

I'd like to utilise MediaWiki for notetaking with the Math extension to show equations, but the equations disrupt the uniform line-height when nested inside paragraphs. Is there any way to make it equal to that of normal text?

Comment: Have you tried using different setting for rendering of the equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that using MathJAX, a client-side implementation of `<math>` rendering renders it very nicely with equal line height. I set the following in `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgUseMathJax = true;
$wgDefaultUserOptions['math'] = MW_MATH_MATHJAX;
```